# Python Most Efficient Way to Search a List

Tags: python

Bear with me as I am very new to Python.  Basically I am looking for the most efficient way to search through a multi-dimensional list.  So say I have the following list:

```
fruit = [
    [banana, 6],
    [apple, 5],
    [banana, 9],
    [apple, 10],
    [pear, 2],
   ]
```

And I wanted the outcome of my function to produce:  Apple: 15, Banana: 15, Pear 2.  What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: The most efficient was is to use an appropriate data structure (read: something with O(1) lookup instead of O(n) linear search).

Comment: What you want to isn't what most people would call searching -- maybe "tallying" or "summarizing".

Comment: What is the data-type of `banana`, `apple`, etc?

Answer (score 9):

That is not in any way a search...

What you want is

```
import collections

def count(items):
    data = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for kind, count in items:
        data[kind] += count
    return data
```

Comment: +1, also, in Python 2.7, you can use `collections.Counter()` rather than `collections.defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
fruit = [['banana', 6], ['apple',5], ['banana',9],['apple',10],['pear',2]]
f = {}

def fruit_count():
    for x in fruit:
    if x[0] not in f.keys():
            f.update({x[0]:x[1]})
    else:
            t = f.get(x[0])
            t = t + x[1]
            f.update({x[0]:t})

    return f
f = {'apple': 15, 'banana': 15, 'pear': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accumulate, and iterate through the list.

```
accum = collections.defaultdict(int)
for e in fruit:
  accum[e[0]] += e[1]
```

Comment: What is `fruit[e]` supposed to be?

Comment: @FolgeBird, @Sven: I was momentarily confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
myHash = {}

fruit = [
    [banana, 6],
    [apple, 5],
    [banana, 9],
    [apple, 10],
    [pear, 2],
   ]

for i in fruit:
   if not i[0] in myHash.keys():
      myHash[i[0]] = 0
   myHash[i[0]] += i[1]

for i in myHash:
   print i, myHash[i]
```

would return

```
apple 15
banana 15
pear 2
```

#### Edit

I didn't know about defaultdict in python.  That is a much better way.

Comment: `dict.setdefault` is another alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what type `apple` and `banana` are, so I made just them empty classes and used their class names for identification. One approach to this problem is to use the dictionary method `setdefault()` which first checks to see if a given key is already in the dictionary and if it is simply returns it, but if it's not, will insert it it with a default value before returning that.

To make more efficient use of it for this problem by avoiding multiple dictionary key lookups, the count associated with each key needs be stored in something "mutable" or changeable since simple integers are not in Python. The trick is to store the numeric count in a one-element `list` which can be changed. The first function in code below shows how this can be done.

Note that the Python `collections` module in the standard library has had a dictionary subclass in it called `defaultdict` which could have been used instead which effectively does the `setdefault()` operation for you whenever a non-existent key is first accessed. It also makes storing the count in a list for efficiency unnecessary and updating it a slightly simpler.

In Python 2.7 another dictionary subclass was added to the `collections` module called `counter`. Using it probably would be the best solution since it was designed for exactly this kind of application. The code below shows how to do it all three ways (and sorts the list of totals created).

```
class apple: pass
class banana: pass
class pear: pass

fruit = [
    [banana, 6],
    [apple, 5],
    [banana, 9],
    [apple, 10],
    [pear, 2],
   ]

# ---- using regular dictionary
def tally(items):
    totals = dict()
    for kind, count in items:
        totals.setdefault(kind, [0])[0] += count
    return sorted([key.__name__,total[0]] for key, total in totals.iteritems())

print tally(fruit)
# [['apple', 15], ['banana', 15], ['pear', 2]]


import collections

# ---- using collections.defaultdict dict subclass
def tally(items):
    totals = collections.defaultdict(int) # requires Python 2.5+
    for kind, count in items:
        totals[kind] += count
    return sorted([key.__name__, total] for key, total in totals.iteritems())

print tally(fruit)
# [['apple', 15], ['banana', 15], ['pear', 2]]


# ---- using collections.Counter dict subclass
def tally(items):
    totals = collections.Counter() # requires Python 2.7+
    for kind, count in items:
        totals[kind] += count
    return sorted([key.__name__, total] for key, total in totals.iteritems())

print tally(fruit)
# [['apple', 15], ['banana', 15], ['pear', 2]]
```